# Same variable names but with different values within two seperate "def" functions. Can they not change down the code somehow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Short example:

```
def Tk1():
    x = 1

def Tk2():
    x = 2
```

I want "x" to not change down the code into the subsequent variable.  Can I have both "x" assigned to different values and not mess up the code within the def?

Comment: Variables are local to each function. They don't interfere with each other.

Comment: Both of your local `x` variables will never even *exist* at the same time - they vanish as soon as the containing function returns.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a variable that is **defined** in the function, will always stay the same in that specific function, however if you define it outside the two functions the value can change depending on which function you call first:

```
a = 0

def f_a():
    a = 10
    return a

def f_b():
    a = 4
    return a

print(f_a())
print(f_b())
```

Will return this result:

```
10
4
```

The way you showed in your question **defines** the variable inside the function meaning it is local to that specific function. Note the fact it isn't a global variable.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you.

Comment: @smar8300 would you mind to mark this answer as correct for anyone that comes across this incase they search about this?

Comment: that code will do that regardless of whether you define a as a global or not. Neither of your functions changes the ``a`` outside the function.